# Regex Fetched from MYSQL is not validating

Tags: java, mysql, regex

```
  for(String paramName:paramNames){
    String regexString = regexPair.get(paramName);
    try{             
        System.out.println(regexString);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexString);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(paramMap.get(paramName)[0]);
        status = m.matches();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(!status)
           break;
}
```

where `regexSring` have value

```
 "^(?!.*[^A-Za-z0-9@])((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z]).{6,20})$"
```

The value of `regexString` is fecthed from mysql db an populated in map and `paramMap.get(paramName)[0]` have value `"dssf55454"` but it is retuning false while it should return true.

If I write the following sample program

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?!.*[^A-Za-z0-9@])((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z]).{6,20})$");
 Matcher m = p.matcher("mal4554SD");
 status = m.matches();
 System.out.println(status);
```

it returns true. Why?

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be in the snippet `\\d` in the `regexString`.

What is the result printed in console?

```
System.out.println(regexString);
```

Also, it will be helpful if you can share more details about `regexPair` and its `get()`.

Comment: the value of System.out.println(regexString); is 
 ^(?!.*[^A-Za-z0-9@])((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z]).{6,20})$
regexPair contain regex for different field

Comment: `\\d` is the root cause.  In your case, `regexPair.get()` should  return `\d`. I mean you expect some digit number.